# SQL - how to add a value with a condition to a selection?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

| name | value | success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 10 | 0 |
| name 2 | 20 | 0 |
| name 2 | 30 | 1 |

And my query is:

```sql
SELECT name, SUM(value) as valueTotal FROM TableName GROUP BY name
```

The result is:

| name | valueTotal |
| --- | --- |
| name 1 | 10 |
| name 2 | 50 |

Now I want to add a new column which will contain the sum of only successful rows. But if I add this condition, it will apply to all selected fields:

```sql
SELECT name, SUM(value) as valueTotal, SUM(value) as successValueTotal FROM TableName WHERE success = 1 GROUP BY name
```

Here is the result I want to get:

| name | valueTotal | successValueTotal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 10 | 0 |
| name 2 | 50 | 30 |

How can I add a field with a separate condition that does not affect the main query? Thx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUM` function with a conditional aggregation on whether *success* is 1 or not. When *success* is 1, then take the value of the *value* field, otherwise sum up 0.

```
SELECT name, 
       SUM(value)                     AS valueTotal,
       SUM(IF(success = 1, value, 0)) AS successValueTotal
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY name
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Rgo5eeFgDkKwpuBq9brTq/0).

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical use case for `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT name, 
SUM(value) AS valueTotal,
SUM(CASE WHEN success = 1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS successValueTotal
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY name
```

You can (like lemon showed) also use an if clause in MYSQL. This is a bit shorter, but the query will not work on every DB while `CASE WHEN` does. So I think both is fine.